# Retrieving data within a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I created a trigger to send a mail whenever the status of an equipment after the servicing is "purchase needed". In the email the warranty and purchase dates are needed, along with the model of the equipment. I have 3 select statements within the trigger. The model is retrieved however the dates does not work and the data is not saved. Here is the trigger below. Everything works if i comment the date apart in the message

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[sendpurchaserequest]
   ON  [dbo].[services]
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    declare @type as varchar(50)
    declare @serial as varchar(50)
    declare @department as varchar(50)
    declare @action as varchar(150)
    declare @status as varchar(50)
    declare @message as Varchar(1000)
    declare @warrant as datetime
    declare @model as varchar(150)
    declare @purchase as varchar(20)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here
    set @type = (select Equipmenttype from inserted)
    set @action = (select supportaction from inserted)
    set @department = (select userdepartment from inserted)
    set @serial = (select serialnum from inserted)
    set @status = (select [status] from inserted)
    set @warrant = (select W_date from Equipment where Serial_no=@serial)
    set @model = (select Model from Equipment where Serial_no=@serial)
    set @purchase = (select P_date from Equipment where Serial_no=@serial)

    if @status = 'Purchase Needed     '
    begin
    set @message = 'Diagnostic tests on the following equipment have revealed that it is in need of replacement parts to be procured.

See details below:</br></br>' + 'Equipment Type:' + @type + '</br> Model: ' + @model +'</br> Serial Number: ' + @serial + '</br></br> User Department: ' + @department + '</br> Corrective Action: ' + @action + '</br> Purchase Date: ' + @purchase + '</br> Warrant Date: ' + @warrant

    print @message

                    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp
                    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                    @recipients='someone@site.com',
                    @body = @message,
                    @subject = 'Purchase Needed for Equipment',
                    @body_format ='HTML'

    end
```

Comment: Just checking but it is right for W_Date to be saved into a datetime field, while P_date is going into a varchar(20)?

Comment: For a `delete` trigger, the `inserted` table should be empty, so most of those assignments will be `null`. But note, also, that I said `inserted` *table*. Even if you switch to using `deleted`, you also need to recognize that it can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. All of those assignments are broken because they seem to assume that trigger tables contain exactly one row - which is an unsound assumption.

Comment: Which dbms? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL...)

Comment: Since @warrant is a datetime variable, you will need to CAST it to varchar when building your message variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give this a try which should perform it for each deleted item - if you want inserted then obviously change it to inserted table but also your instead of should be insert:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[sendpurchaserequest]
   ON  [dbo].[services]
   after insert
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    declare @type as varchar(50)
    declare @serial as varchar(50)
    declare @department as varchar(50)
    declare @action as varchar(150)
    declare @status as varchar(50)
    declare @message as Varchar(1000)
    declare @warrant as datetime
    declare @model as varchar(150)
    declare @purchase as datetime

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

    Declare email cursor fast_forward for
    Select i.Equipmenttype, i.supportaction, i.userdepartment, i.serialnum, i.[status], e.W_date, e.Model, e.P_date
    from inserted i
    inner join 
    Equipment e on e.Serial_no = i.serial

    Open email

    Fetch next from email into @type, @action, @department, @serial, @status, @warrant, @model, @purchase

    While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin

    if @status = 'Purchase Needed'
    begin
    set @message = 'Diagnostic tests on the following equipment have revealed that it is in need of replacement parts to be procured.

See details below:</br></br>' + 'Equipment Type:' + ISNULL(@type, '') + '</br> Model: ' + ISNULL(@model, '') +'</br> Serial Number: ' + ISNULL(@serial, '') + '</br></br> User Department: ' + ISNULL(@department, '') + '</br> Corrective Action: ' + ISNULL(@action, '') + '</br> Purchase Date: ' + ISNULL(Cast(@purchase as varchar),'') + '</br> Warrant Date: ' + ISNULL(Cast(@warrant as varchar), '')

    print @message

                    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_start_sp
                    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                    @recipients='someone@site.com',
                    @body = @message,
                    @subject = 'Purchase Needed for Equipment',
                    @body_format ='HTML'
    end
    Fetch next from email into @type, @action, @department, @serial, @status, @warrant, @model, @purchase
    end
End
```

Incidentally I also noticed your @purchase is varchar(20) are you sure your P_date is a varchar(20)? If not you will need to cast it as this

Comment: My purchase and warranty had datetime type but that didn't work so i tried varchar. The trigger should say after insert as well

Comment: @user3590040 I've amended the above and this should hopefully work now

Comment: Email is sent but the body is empty

Comment: I think you probably need a Set concat_null_yields_null off at the beginning as a null must be getting returned in one of the variables and causing everything to be returned null. If that works then you're best to add isnull() to your variables for future proofing

Comment: Tried the concat_null_yields and emails are still empty

Comment: OK try the amended above. I think I know what the problem was, you had "if @status = 'Purchase Needed     '". "@status" is a varchar so it will remove the end spaces so this should have been "if @ status = 'Purchase Needed'". I've tightened it up with isnull statements too, so this should hopefully work now

Comment: Just to clarify as that comment didn't show up very well. The if statement for status had Purchase Needed followed by spaces.

Comment: The problem occurs with the purchase date and warrant date because the user will not have these dates all the time. If the dates are available the email is sent with all the details. if any of the date is NULL then the email is empty.

Comment: @user3590040 The above code that I amended yesterday should tackle this ok, have you tried it?

Comment: Got it to work. I used convert instead of cast though. Thanks for your help